# React Native Flatlist text change

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I change the my code related to answer.

```
import React, { useState, } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";


const ToggleButton = (props) => {
    const {
        sample,
        id,
        onPress,
    } = props;
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
    const text = isPressed ? `${sample}-${id}` : sample;

    return (

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            setIsPressed(!isPressed);
            onPress && onPress();
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, }}>        
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", height: 100, borderWidth: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{ text }</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
};

const ToggleExample =() => {
    const data = [
        { sample:"John Doe1", id:"1" },
        { sample:"John Doe2", id:"2" },
        { sample:"John Doe3", id:"3" },
        { sample:"John Doe4", id:"4" },
        { sample:"John Doe5", id:"5" },  
    ];
    const data2 = [
      { sample2:"Sample2 Doe1", id:"1" },
      { sample2:"Sample2 Doe2", id:"2" },
      { sample2:"Sample2 Doe3", id:"3" },
      { sample2:"Sample2 Doe4", id:"4" },
      { sample2:"Sample2 Doe5", id:"5" },  
  ];

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={entry => {
                const { item } = entry;
                return (<ToggleButton {...item} />);
            }}
            contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20, }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => { return (<View style={{ flex: 1, height: 10, }}/>) }}
            keyExtractor={(entry, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

My thing is when touch the any list item data(it comes fromd data array) it will change the text related to data2 array value with the same id

John Doe1

John Doe2

John Doe3 <- touch then

John Doe1

John Doe2

Sample2 Doe3 <- Change text to this

Like this text changing line

```
const text = isPressed ? `${sample}-${id}` : sample;

be like
const text = isPressed ? `${sample2}-${id}` : sample;
```

If it's not possible, this type will be enough

```
  const data = [
    { sample: 'John Doe', id: '1' },
    { sample: 'John Doe', id: '2' },
    { sample: 'John Doe', id: '3' },
    { sample: 'John Doe', id: '4' },
    { sample: 'John Doe', id: '5' },
    { sample: 'Samplee2 Doe1', id: '6' },
    { sample: 'Samplee2 Doe2', id: '7' },
    { sample: 'Samplee2 Doe3', id: '8' },
    { sample: 'Samplee2 Doe4', id: '9' },
    { sample: 'Samplee2 Doe5', id: '10' }
  ];
  const text = isPressed ? `${sample}-${id+5}` : sample;
```

Thanks for your interest and effort in advance

Comment: Whats the change you want to do ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I explained but, I just want is change the text which is touched

Comment: It changes the touched item text to sample2 data with key's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two data set so you need to filter data
check this example may work for you https://snack.expo.io/@jsfit/223f2c

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const ToggleButton = (props) => {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const { sample, id, onPress, item1, item2 } = props;
  const text = isPressed ? item2.sample2 : item1.sample;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setIsPressed(!isPressed);
        onPress && onPress();
      }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
          borderWidth: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const ToggleExample = () => {
  const data = [
    { sample: 'John Doe1', id: '1' },
    { sample: 'John Doe2', id: '2' },
    { sample: 'John Doe3', id: '3' },
    { sample: 'John Doe4', id: '4' },
    { sample: 'John Doe5', id: '5' },
  ];
  const data2 = [
    { sample2: 'Sample2 Doe1', id: '1' },
    { sample2: 'Sample2 Doe2', id: '2' },
    { sample2: 'Sample2 Doe3', id: '3' },
    { sample2: 'Sample2 Doe4', id: '4' },
    { sample2: 'Sample2 Doe5', id: '5' },
  ];

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={(entry) => {
          const { item } = entry;
          return (
            <ToggleButton
              item1={item}
              item2={data2.filter((_item) => _item.id === item.id)[0]}
            />
          );
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
          return <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 10 }} />;
        }}
        keyExtractor={(entry, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yess, thank you so much thats what I tryed. I started react yesterday and I'm still learning. Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";


const ToggleButton = (props) => {
    const {
        sample,
        id,
        onPress,
    } = props;
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
    const text = isPressed ? `${sample}-${id}` : sample;

    return (

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            setIsPressed(!isPressed);
            onPress && onPress();
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, }}>        
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", height: 100, borderWidth: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{ text }</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
};

const ToggleExample =() => {
    const data = [
        { sample:"John Doe", id:"1" },
        { sample:"John Doe", id:"2" },
        { sample:"John Doe", id:"3" },
        { sample:"John Doe", id:"4" },
        { sample:"John Doe", id:"5" },  
    ];

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={entry => {
                const { item } = entry;
                return (<ToggleButton {...item} />);
            }}
            contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20, }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => { return (<View style={{ flex: 1, height: 10, }}/>) }}
            keyExtractor={(entry, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default ToggleExample;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it is very good example but not the real I want to do.

Comment: " const text = isPressed ? `${sample}-${id}` : sample; " you wrote. When pressed add"-id" . I want is when pressed set the sample2 data with the id's value

Comment: Don't expect a perfect answer. The code above sets a good foundation for solving your specific use case. Anyway, try this update to the code: const text = isPressed ? `${id}` : sample;